# jQuery AJAX not working in any IE, but fine in Firefox, Opera, Chrome and Safari

Tags: jquery, validation

I am working on a client's site, which should of been a one second job of just adding a contact form and the Validate plugin.

I thought all was well until I got to IE.

All other browsers work absolutley perfectly, but After hours of tinkering I have 50% fixed the IE issues.  Now I really am stuck.

It took me ages to get the validation plugin working as desired, before it didn't even show up.

Now after downgrading to jQuery v1.5.2 and using Validate v1.8 the errors show up and the submit if prevented.

But now it won't submit the form when it is okay.

Here is the code I have that works fine in all other browsers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#node").hide();
    $("#success").hide();
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
    $("#contact_form").validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var str = $(form).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'http://www.french-tuition.co.uk/proccess_contact.php',
                dataType: 'text',
                cache: false,
                data: 'ajax=true&' + str,
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (msg) {
                    $("#node").ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
                        result = msg;
                        $("#node").html(result);
                        if (msg == 'success') {
                            $("#node").hide();
                            $("#contact_form").fadeOut("slow");
                            $("#success").fadeIn("slow");
                        } else {
                            result = msg;
                            $("#node").html(result);
                            $("#node").fadeIn("slow");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The error is definitely within the submit function handler (I tested by adding `alert();` function to check. I can get as far as just before the ajax call with the alert function, but not after.)

So something is going on with IE and this function

Comment: why do you have an ajaxComplete bind inside of an ajax success handler? that shouldn't fire unless you successfully submitted this thing twice

Answer (score 3):

Why are you binding the ajaxComplete handler on #node within your success function?  Can't you change to this:

```
success: function (msg) {
    if (msg == 'success') {
        $("#node").hide();
        $("#contact_form").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#success").fadeIn("slow");
    } else {
        $("#node").html(msg);
        $("#node").fadeIn("slow");
    }
}
```

Comment: almost there. Now try not suggesting that he nest an "if success" inside of a handler which can only fire "if success"

Comment: Eh, that looks to me like a custom message he's implementing.  So in his case, there could very well be a "success"-ful response (meaning a 200) that actually indicates something other than a "success" (from the point of view of his business logic).  Not really something that we can assume is incorrect.

Comment: fair enough. I think it's more likely that it's code he copy-pasted (like the complete inside of a success) though

Comment: yes the code was copy pasted, i removed what was there and what you posted worked great. thanks